# Shaky/Bounce effect while using SnapHelper on Scroll in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, pagersnaphelper

I have tried both SnapHelper Linear and Pager But in both cases the below effect shown in the gif happens on scrolling up

https://media4.giphy.com/media/CN0FsbuoNG9d9DhFqd/giphy.gif

I have attached a linear layout manager

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/oc_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
        
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

in class

```
private fun stickyScroll(){
        val helper: SnapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(binding?.ocList)
}
```

and also tried this code to get a similar effect of pager in linear Snap Helper

```
val snapHelper: LinearSnapHelper = object : LinearSnapHelper() {
            override fun findTargetSnapPosition(
                layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager,
                velocityX: Int,
                velocityY: Int
            ): Int {
                val centerView = findSnapView(layoutManager) ?: return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
                val position = layoutManager.getPosition(centerView)
                var targetPosition = -1
                if (layoutManager.canScrollHorizontally()) {
                    targetPosition = if (velocityX < 0) {
                        position - 1
                    } else {
                        position + 1
                    }
                }
                if (layoutManager.canScrollVertically()) {
                    targetPosition = if (velocityY < 0) {
                        position - 1
                    } else {
                        position + 1
                    }
                }
                val firstItem = 0
                val lastItem = layoutManager.itemCount - 1
                targetPosition = Math.min(lastItem, Math.max(targetPosition, firstItem))
                return targetPosition
            }
        }

        snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding?.ocList)
```